# creating PNG plots on the linux terminal

Tags: linux, r

I have an R script that I run on a linux server (Debian Wheezy 7.7). This script is meant to do some computations and generate plots into PNGs. Unfortunatelly I get an error:

```
> savePlot("myplot", "png")
Error in savePlot("myplot", "png") :
  can only copy from 'X11(type="*cairo")' devices
```

How do I get around this? I am only connected from Win XP with PuTTy, I don't have any X-windows set up on my XP and I don't want to bother with this - all I need is to run the script and produce the PNGs. Thanks!

Comment: How about plotting to the PNG device?  See `?png`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I was used to savePlot (on Win XP) as it was more comfortable, but I will try this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have more luck calling the device internally:

```
png("plot.png")
    plot(1)
dev.off()
```

If you don't want to bother with opening an instance of R, you could save the above script (e.g. "script.01.R") and run the following from the console:

```
R CMD BATCH script.01.R
```

This should also work to create the .png.

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu distribution, calling `x11()` before `plot()` resolved this issue. [This blog post](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.ca/2012/01/graphics-plots-in-r-for-macos-linux-and.html) gives more details on different operating systems.